# How can I use the info from the parent class in a child object?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

```py
  class Animal:
       def eat(self):
           print("eats well")
       def sleep(self):
           print("sleeps well")

   class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self,breed,color):
           self.breed= breed
           self.color= color
   Canela=Dog("chihuahua","brown")

   print("This dog is a",Canela.breed,"and its color is",Canela.color)

   #untill there ir works but how can I add the information from the parent class, If I do
   print("This dog is a",Canela.breed,"and its color is",Canela.color,"and",Canela.eat())
```

It appears It eats well at the top and none next to the sentence. How can I write it well?

Comment: Who is *Perro*? :D  Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start.

Comment: It's probably `Dog` but just a guess.

Comment: As a general rule, let your functions return strings rather than print them. You can do whatever you want with a returned string, but nothing with one that got printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's is because your eat function print to the stdout and does not return a string.
you need to change your eat function to be:

```
def eat(self):
    return "eats well"
```

Comment: Okay thank you that works but, what is the difference in writing print or return? That return simply changes what you write for the sentence while print needs you to write something?